# Unable to query MongoDB database with node.js and Mongodb package

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I cant query my MongoDB database with node.js and Mongodb package.

I have succesfully inserted 2 objects like so:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;
var db = new mongo.Db("nodejs-introduction", new mongo.Server(host, port, { }), {safe: true});
console.log(host);
db.open(function(error) {
    console.log("We are connected ", + host + ':' + port);

    db.collection("user", { w:1 }, function(error, collection){
        console.log("We have the collection");

        collection.insert({
            id: "1",
            name: "Foo Bar",
            twitter: "Foo_Bar",
            email: "info@nfoobar.com"
        }, {w:1}, function() {
            console.log("Succesfully inserted Foo Bar");
        });

        collection.insert({
            id: "2",
            name: "Bar Foo",
            twitter: "Bar_Foo",
            email: "info@tbarfoo.com"
        }, {w:1}, function() {
            console.log("Succesfully inserted Bar Foo");
        });
    });
});
```

Everything goes fine here, no errors. But if i want to query items like so:

```
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;
var db = new mongo.Db("nodejs-introduction", new mongo.Server(host, port, { }), {safe: false});
console.log(host);
db.open(function(error) {
    console.log("We are connected ", + host + ':' + port);

    //collection is sort of table
    db.collection("user", function(error, collection){
        console.log("We have the collection");
        collection.find({ "id": "1" }, function(error, cursor){
            cursor.toArray(function(error, users){
                if (users.length == 0) {
                    console.log("no user found");
                } else {
                    console.log("Found a user", users[0]); 
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Then i get the following error:

```
127.0.0.1
We are connected  NaN:27017
We have the collection

/path/to/query.js:14
                if (users.length == 0) {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

So what i understand is that the variable users is null and that it can't find any matches  but i don't know why. What is it that iam doing wrong?

Comment: Probably there is no element `users` in the document, and thus returning `null`. You will have to check for `null`:  if (users == null) { ... } else ...

Comment: There were no matches, so it returns `null` rather than an empty `Array`.

Comment: I understand that, but what i don't understand is why there are no matches.

Comment: Try your query from the mongo shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Mongodb was not running. How is it that i can insert to MongoDB without any errors if Mongodb is not running?